# SARA R410M AT Command Abort

Tags: at-command

I am trying to set up my system to be able to abort AT commands that can be aborted. According to the documentation from the U-Blox SARA R410M-02B-01 a command is aborted by sending a character to the DCE during the command execution:

[image]

Page 4, from [AT Commands Manual](https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/SARA-R4_ATCommands_UBX-17003787.pdf).

I am testing the system by issuing the command `AT+COPS=?` which according to the datasheet can be aborted:

[image]

and then sending a character through UART to the SARA modem to abort. So far, I haven´t got any success and the command is always executed. I have tried with all characters in the UTF-8 (using a `for` loop) except for the ending char [0x00]. Moreover, I have tried to send the char with and without the line ending expected by the modem[CRLF].

From the UART event handler, I know the chars have being received by the modem. So I am sure it´s not a communication issue. I dunno what else to try, any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So far, I haven´t got any success and the command is always executed.

How do you determine success? Is the issue that the command sends an `OK` *Final result code* and you expect it not to when the command is being aborted or is the issue that the command continues on executing for several seconds/minutes after the abort character has been sent and the abort attempt seems to have no effect?

---

In the first case, the expected behaviour is to always send a final result code even when a commands is aborted. This means that in practice there is no way to verify that a command has been aborted because all modems just sends an `OK` which is indistinguishable from a normal successful execution result (In theory a modem could perhaps return a custom result code like `+CME ERROR: Aborted command +COPS` but I have never heard about such thing and seriously doubt that it exists).

From [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) chapter *"5.6.1 Aborting commands"*:

> When such an aborting event is recognized by the DCE, it shall terminate
> the command in progress and return an appropriate result code to the DTE,
> as specified for the particular command.

(DCE (data communication equipment) here means modem and DTE (data terminal equipment) the sender of AT commands)

---

In the second case, you might just be out of luck and the device have no or limited support for actually aborting the command. The software that runs in the modem is most likely divided into several processes. The process that receives and parses AT commands will not have logic to communicate with the mobile network, that will be handled by some other process. So when the AT parsing process receives `AT+COPS` it will initiate some inter process communication to get the network process to do the required work and wait for the result so it can generate the response to the AT command. Depending on how the software is written there might be blocking calls that prevents the modem for aborting commands immediately.

Comment: My stardard for success would be that the either, receiving any response (`ok`, `error`, or even other custom) different than the usual response with the available networks to register to. Even sending the data it has gather until receiving the abort command, I would understand that as an abort. Neither of that happens, I send the abort and the command keeps running because much later I receive the networks data.

Comment: I honestly not worried about the kind of response that the abort command causes, I can deal with any response in the code. But I would like to be able to stop any of the modem long commands like `COPS`.

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility that the modem doesn´t support it. These datasheets are never 100% accurate., more considering they are used for various models of U-blox modems.